Ranking 6 algorithms based on complexity
Problem: The file numere.in stores at least 3 numbers and at most 1000000 natural numbers with up to nine digits. It asks you to display on the screen how many digits were used to write these numbers.
I have resolved it using 6 methods:

Using Digits Iteratively

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    int n, nr = 0;

    while (f >> n)

    {

        while (n)

        {

            nr++;

            n /= 10;

        }

    }

    cout << nr;

    f.close();

}



Using Range Multipliers

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    int n, nr1 = 0, nr2 = 0, nr3 = 0, nr4 = 0, nr5 = 0, nr6 = 0, nr7 = 0, nr8 = 0, nr9 = 0;

    while (f >> n)

    {

        if (n < 10)

            nr1++;

        else if (n < 100)

            nr2++;

        else if (n < 1000)

            nr3++;

        else if (n < 10000)

            nr4++;

        else if (n < 100000)

            nr5++;

        else if (n < 1000000)

            nr6++;

        else if (n < 10000000)

            nr7++;

        else if (n < 100000000)

            nr8++;

        else if (n < 1000000000)

            nr9++;

    }

    nr2 *= 2;

    nr3 *= 3;

    nr4 *= 4;

    nr5 *= 5;

    nr6 *= 6;

    nr7 *= 7;

    nr8 *= 8;

    nr9 *= 9;

    cout << nr1 + nr2 + nr3 + nr4 + nr5 + nr6 + nr7 + nr8 + nr9;

    f.close();

    return 0;

}


Using Division Checks

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    int n, nr = 0;

    while (f >> n)

    {

        nr++;

        if (n / 10)

            nr++;

        if (n / 100)

            nr++;

        if (n / 1000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 10000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 100000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 1000000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 10000000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 100000000)

            nr++;

        if (n / 1000000000)

            nr++;

    }

    cout << nr;

    f.close();

    return 0;

}


Using minimum and maximum values

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <cmath>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    int min, max, i, j, nri = 0, nrj = 0, s = 0, copie;

    f >> min;

    while (f >> max)

        continue;

    i = min;

    j = max;

    while (i)

    {

        nri++;

        i /= 10;

    }

    while (j)

    {

        nrj++;

        j /= 10;

    }

    copie = nrj;

    while (nrj > nri + 1)

    {

        s += (pow(10, nrj - 1) - pow(10, nrj - 2)) * (nrj - 1) + nrj;

        nrj--;

    }

    s += (copie - 1) * (max - pow(10, copie - 1) + 1);

    s += (pow(10, nri) - min) * nri;

    cout << s;

    f.close();

    return 0;

}


Using String Length

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    char n[10];

    int nr = 0;

    while (f >> n)

        nr += strlen(n);

    cout << nr << endl;

    f.close();

    return 0;

}


Using to_string()

#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;



int main()

{

    ifstream f("numere.in");

    int n, nr = 0;

    while (f >> n)

        nr += to_string(n).size();

    cout << nr << endl;

    f.close();

    return 0;

}

I want to rank them based on their complexity in time and space.
Let be:
N = number of integers in the file
M = the maximum value of the integers
My guesses are:
Program 1:
Time: O(N * lg M)
Space: O(1)
Program 2:
Time: O(N)
Space: O(1)
Program 3:
Time: O(N)
Space: O(1)
Program 4:
Time: O(1)
Space: O(1)
Program 5:
Time: O(N * log M)
Space: O(1)
Program 6:
Time: O(N * log M)
Space: O(1)
Based on these, the corect order should be
4 < 2 < 3 < 1 < 5 < 6
Is this correct?
